# opam 2.0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, ppa

[opam 2.0](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#Ubuntu) has been release for a while. I was wondering if there is any repository for installing it on Ubuntu (18.04 LTS as of Oct 2018).

I searched on bing.com and couldn't find any mention. The [OPAM website](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/wiki/Distributions) itself says the current supported version is 1.2.2, but listed under the "Other" category,

> Distribution  Latest OPAM     Maintainer  Notes
>
> Ubuntu Linux (PPA)    2.0.0   Anil Madhavapeddy (@avsm)   Anil's official
>   OPAM PPA Travis and discuss post

But the [linked website](https://launchpad.net/%7Eavsm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) therein show no recent activity (with the last being 151 weeks ago). Trying `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa` also gives an error below.

Does anyone know how to use the repository correctly?

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
 Latest stable versions of OCaml and OPAM.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~avsm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

...

Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/avsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/avsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/opam-2-0-experimental-ppas/2446

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `avsm` ppa now contains the current stable version of opam (2.x), as of Jan 2019:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install opam
```